# How global are global variables in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Here's a ruby script:

```
discarded_rows=-1

def foobar(line)

    if line.match('records discarded: *(\d+)') then
       discarded_rows=$1;
       puts('yepp, I have found: ' + discarded_rows);
    end;

end


foobar('records successful:    99    ');
foobar('records discarded:      2    ');
foobar('records unknown:        8    ');

if discarded_rows != 2 then
   puts("discarded_rows: #{discarded_rows}");
end
```

And here's what I believe it does: it declares a (global) variable with the name `discarded_rows`. It then declares a function `foobar` that checks if the passed argument `line` matches "records discarded *\d". If it does, it assignes the number of discarded records to the (what I think is a global) variable `discarded_rows`. If it matches, it also prints "yepp...." just to make sure
that the match works.

The function is called, with one string that should match.

If `discarded_rows` is not equal to 2, it prints the according value.

And here's the script's output:

```
yepp, I have found: 2
discarded_rows: -1
```

So, clearly, the match worked, and obviously, `discarded_rows` is not truly global. Is this correct or do I overlook something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`discarded_rows` is not a global variable. `$discarded_rows` would be a global variable.

Answer (score 3):

Zabba is absolutely correct. To elaborate a little bit however, `discarded_rows` is a local variable. Code at the top level is treated roughly as though the whole file was being executed as a method. Defining a new method actually happens much more so at runtime than in most languages, to the point where you can write something like

```
s = gets
if s =~ /(\d+)/
   i = $1.to_i
   if i < 5
     def less_than_five
       true
     end
   else
     def less_than_five
       false
     end
    end
 else
   def less_than_five
     raise "not a number"
   end
end

p less_than_five
```

The body of an `def end` block introduces a new lexical scope that does not close over the enclosing lexical scope (locals in the surrounding code are not available to the body of the method).